# The pod is problem in state using rocksdb in Flink

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

My Flink App has some issues so I tried to investigate the metrics using prometheus.

As you can see in the figure below, the figure is about the `numRecordsInPerSecond` in the Flink consuming from the Kafka. And note that at the `19:00~20:00`, there is some gap in the line.After then, the lines are not smoothly connected before `00:00`. There are so many break point between `19:50` and `00:00`.

[image]

I think that there some issue at the `19:50` because it is first time break seen in the figure.

My flink app is running on the kubernetes and I searched the `off heap` metrics because my app is using state and rocksdb. After looking at the offheap metrics as shown in the figure below, there are so many up and down in the `20:10~24:00`.

[image]

I thought that it must be related to the exception issue for my flink app.

But I am wondering that the first appearing time is not the `19:50` which is beginning point of the break at `numRecordsPerSecond` in the first figure above.

Anyway, I tried to analyze the off heap metrics for each pod as shown the figure below.

One pod has significant up for off heap but there is no significant issue around `19:50`.

In my assumption, the off heap issue is happened around `19:50` and the flink app is down due to it and then, it repeatedly consumed the data from kafka using the latest succeed checkpoint offset. So it crashed many time from `19:50` and it resolved after `00:00`.

But I don't have any informative clues regarding the metric issue around `19:50`. In addition, I don't know why the line is broken between `20:00` and `00:00` in one of the off heap figure.

My question is that why my app has break part in the `numRecordsPerSecond` and how to analyze it more for ensuring the root cause?

In addition, I found that the log of my app had out of memory issue when above case is found. But when I see the off heap metrics as above, I don't have any noticeable issues regarding out of memory.

[image]

Could you help me?

My flink version is `1.11`.